# Ignore e-mails about missing ALLOWED_HOSTS entry for one hostname

Tags: django

I have configured my application so it accepts requests with my FQDN in the `Host:` header (using `ALLOWED_HOSTS`). However, our backend team monitors the site with a different address (just a HTTP “ping” to check if the application is alive). I don’t need to serve any pages on this second site, however, getting e-mails about a missing `ALLOWED_HOSTS` entry for this particular case is a bit annoying (it comes every five minutes).

I have found several articles that discuss how to disable such notifications all at once, but I’d like to ignore this for only this one host. Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could solve this by addding a `filter` to the `mail_admins` and silencing the specific `django.security.DisallowedHost` log record. [Docs.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/logging/#django.utils.log.CallbackFilter)

When a non-valid host is received a `django.core.exceptions.SuspiciousOperation` is raised which is logged by `django.security.DisallowedHost` logger and handled by default by `mail_admins` logging handler.

By adding a `django.utils.log.CallbackFilter` filter to the `mail_admins` handler you could silent the log record you want. In this case silenting the `mail_admins` handler will avoid sending an email.

An example `LOGGING` settings would look like this (I will only add the relevant bits, your settings will probably have more entries):

```
def skip_missing_host(record):
    if record.name == 'django.security.DisallowedHost':
        # `record.msg` contents are similar to:
        # u"Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'somehost'.
        # You may need to add u'somehost' to ALLOWED_HOSTS."

        # Add condition to determine when the ERROR should be logged:
        if "u'somehost'" in record.msg:
            # Returning False indicates that the record shouldn't be handled:
            return False
    return True


LOGGING = {
    'filters': {
        'skip_missing_host': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.CallbackFilter',
            'callback': skip_missing_host,
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false', 'skip_missing_host'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        },
    },
}
```

Alternatively you could create your own `django.security.DisallowedHost` handler, which would need to be configured in the `LOGGING` setting.

Comment: Yes, I have figured this out, I was hoping that I missed something in the settings file, something like maybe IGNORE_ALLOWED_HOST. I will use this approach, then!